# Android: TextViews not centered in the columns of the GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am creating a 2x3 `GridLayout` in my Android application. The three columns are supposed to have equal width and the `TextViews` are supposed to be centered in the columns. However, my layout is the image below, where not all the `TextViews` are horizontally aligned within their columns. This happens despite the fact that I set the `gravity` to `center_horizontal` for each of the `TextViews`.

**For example**: the `TextView` with the text "abcd" leans more to the right.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/overall_statistics"
        >
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="2"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:text="4452"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:text="abcdef"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="2000"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16sp"
                android:text="abcd"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16sp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="2252"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16sp"
                android:text="abcdefgh"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </GridLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `android:paddingLeft="16sp"` of your textViews in 2nd and 3rd columns

Comment: Also, please use `sp` only for text sizes. Because it is scaled by the user’s font size preference. And `dp` for everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:paddingLeft="16sp"` of your textViews in 2nd and 3rd columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/overall_statistics"
        >
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="2"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:text="4452"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:text="abcdef"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="2000"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:text="abcd"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="2252"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:text="abcdefgh"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </GridLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</LinearLayout>
```